# Splunk - counting numeric information in events

Tags: splunk

I'm very new to Splunk and wanted to know if the following was possible:  I'm trying to set up a dashboard of how many times we had to retry a call to a service. I am currently logging the following text:

`number of retries required 0`

The number of retries required can vary from 0 to 3

Is there an easy way to query this and display how many times it was either 0, 1, 2 or 3?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that string the whole event? Will it always look like that (i.e. ending the number of retries?

Comment: Yea, thats correct, it will always end in the number of retries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of it is that you need to extract that piece of information into a field and than analyze that field according to your wishes (i.e. via `timechart`, `chart`, `stats`, etc.) Here are two different ways:

1. you can use the [Field Extractor](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/Knowledge/ExtractfieldsinteractivelywithIFX) to extract and create a new field from the retries count. This is the recommended long-term option.
2. use the [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkInvestigate/Current/SearchReference/Rex) command to extract and define a new field inline.

   `search * | rex field=_raw ".+retries required (?<retries>\d)$"`

Then you can chart them over time by appending `| timechart retries` or use the `stats` command to do some other calculations.